# CSS Styling for Radio Button Forms

Tags: css

I want my labels to be right aligned, but it messes up my radio buttons.  I need the button and label to be closer together and the two options should be closer together. I've tried a number of things and I can't seem to get it right.
This is what the form currently looks like:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is what my HTML looks like for the radio buttons

```css
#wrapper {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left:4%;
    }
    div#formcol1 {
        float:left; 
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    label {
        margin-right: .3em;
        width: 6.3em;  /* I made this deliberately wide – come up with your own optimal width */
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: inline-block; /* width will not work for “inline” elements such as “label”. Therefore we need to set it to “inline-block” */
        text-align: right;
    }
    #formcol1 li {
        list-style:none;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin: 5px
    }
    input[type=text]{
        width: 40%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    
    }
    input[type=radio] {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    /* adds highlights to current fields */
    input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
        padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
        margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
        border: 5px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
```

```html
<div id="multchoice">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Type of Presentation</legend>
        <p><span><input value = "1" id = "TypeofPres_lec" name="p-type" type = "radio" /> 
            <label for = "TypeofPres_lec">Lecture</label></span>
           
            <span><input value = "2" id = "TypeofPres_lab" name="p-type" type = "radio" /> 
                <label for = "TypeofPres_lab">Lab</label></span></p>     
    </fieldset> 

    <p class="submit-button">    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit your proposal" /></p>
</div> <!-- end of multchoice div -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your input inside the label tag.

```css
  #wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

div#formcol1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

label {
  margin-right: .3em;
  width: 6.3em;
  /* I made this deliberately wide – come up with your own optimal width */
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* width will not work for “inline” elements such as “label”. Therefore we need to set it to “inline-block” */
  text-align: right;
}

#formcol1 li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 5px
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/* adds highlights to current fields */

input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
```

```html
<div id="multchoice">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Type of Presentation</legend>
    <p><span>
    <label for = "TypeofPres_lec">
<input value = "1" id = "TypeofPres_lec" name="p-type" type = "radio" /> Lecture
</label>

<label for = "TypeofPres_lab">
<input value = "2" id = "TypeofPres_lab" name="p-type" type = "radio" /> Lab 
</label>
    </span></p>
  </fieldset>

  <p class="submit-button">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit your proposal" /></p>
```

Comment: No problem! If you wouldn't mind marking this answer as solved I would appreciate it!